# How can I move a commit across a merge commit?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, revision-history

Suppose I have a repository like this:

```
I --- C --- M    master
  \       /
   `- A -´       topic
```

where `M` is a merge commit incorporating `topic` into `master`.

Later I find a bug in `C`, so I make a commit fixing it on the `master` branch, on top of `M`:

```
I --- C --- M --- C1    master
  \       /
   `- A -´              topic
```

but ideally I would like the history to look like this:

```
I --- C --- C1 --- M    master
  \              /
   `- A --------´       topic
```

How can I rewrite the history so that `C1` appears before the merge `M`?

I could remove `M`, apply the patch made by `C1`, and merge `topic` into `master` again, resolving all the conflicts again, but I'd like to avoid the effort, and I'd prefer to preserve the original commit information (author, date, etc.) if possible, which rules out doing `git commit` again. I hope it's possible with `git rebase`, but I failed, with either one or both of `-p` and `-i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found is:

```
git checkout -b tmp master^^
# Now tmp is on top of C

git cherry-pick master
# Now tmp is on top of C1', a copy of C1

git rebase -p tmp master
# Now master is on top of a merge commit from C1' and A

git branch -d tmp
```

I don't know why `git rebase` cannot do this all at once without `git cherry-pick`, but at least I know this works.

Comment: Did the merge commit created by `git rebase -p` is correctly created? As in, do its parents are correctly `C1'` and `A`? I have had issues when rebasing merges, as the merge changes get replayed as normal commit instead of merge commit.

Comment: @LopSae: Yes, the merge commit is made on top of C1' and A. Preserving merges is the point of `-p` (a.k.a. `--preserve-merges`), but there's a bug about using `-p` and `-i` together mentioned in `git-rebase(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a single rebase to move the commit (or any number of commits) and then redoing the merge from topic.

```
# Create some branches just for readability
git branch mergeCommit master^
git branch beforeMerge master^^

# Run the rebase
git rebase --onto beforeMerge mergeCommit master
# After the rebase master will have the replayed commits on top of C

# Redo the merge
git merge topic
```

With this rebase you can move more that one commit before the merge. You could read the rebase instruction in plan english as:

> Grab the commits from `mergeCommit` to `master` and rebase them on top of `beforeMerge`.

Comment: Yes, I see that the branches are just for readability indeed; you could do the same just with two commands: `git rebase --onto master^^ master^ master` followed by `git merge topic`. (Not having to delete the temporary branches is an added bonus.)

Answer (score 1):

The commit M in your 3rd graph is not the same as M in the 2nd, since it has different ancestry. Therefore you have to reset master back before M, or use rebase to do it.

First commit your fix and then use `git rebase -i` to move the new commit before M.

To avoid having to resolve conflicts again, make sure you have `rerere.enabled` set to get git to remember resolutions. You have to do this before you first resolve it though so it gets remembered. Rerere (reuse recorded resolutions) is a fantastic feature.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the `git rebase -i` command in more detail? I tried `git rebase -i C`, and the merge is lost; I tried `git rebase -i -p C`, and the `C1` commit is lost, even though I did "pick" commit in the interactive mode.